# Get ancestor object of un-saved object in Hobo

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, hobo

I'm working on a Hobo app trying to tie together a few models properly.

`Activity` objects have many `Page` children. They also have many `DataSet` children.

`Page` objects have several different kinds of children. We'll talk about `Widget` children, but there are several types with the same issue. An instance of a `Widget` belongs to a `Page` but also has a `belongs_to` relationship with a `DataSet`. Here's the important point: the `DataSet` must belong to the containing `Activity`. So for any given `@widget`:

```
@widget.page.activity === @widget.data_set.activity
```

It's easy enough to enforce this constraint in the model with a validation on save. The trick is presenting, within the `Widget`'s form, a select menu of available `DataSet`s which only contains `DataSet`s for the current `Activity`

I was able to get this working for existing objects using a tag like this:

```
<data_set-tag: options="&DataSet.activity_is(&this.page.activity)" />
```

However, for a *new* `Widget`, this fails messily, because either `&this` or `&this.page` is not yet set. Even for a route which contains the page ID, like `/pages/:page_id/widgets/new`, I'm not really able to get an `Activity` to scope the list of `DataSet`s with.

If this was proper Rails, I'd get in to the relevant controller method and make the `Activity` available to the view as `@activity` or something of the sort, but in Hobo the controllers seems to be 95% Magic™ and I don't know where to start. The knowledge of which `Activity` is current must be in there somewhere; how do I get it out?

This is Hobo 1.3.x on Rails 3.0.x.

---

ETA: The code producing the errors is in the `form` tag for `Widget`, like so:

```
<extend tag="form" for="Widget">
  <old-form merge>
    <field-list: fields="&this.field_order">
      <data_set-tag: options="&DataSet.activity_is(&this.page.activity)" />
    </field-list>
  </old-form>
</extend>
```

As I said above, this works for editing existing `Widget`s, but not new `Widget`s; the error is `undefined method 'page' for nil:NilClass`. Bryan Larsen's answer seems to suggest that `&this.page` should not be null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, it turned out to be syntax. Instead of

```
<data_set-tag: options="&DataSet.activity_is(&this.page.activity)" />
```

I needed

```
<data_set-tag: options="&DataSet.activity_is(@this.page.activity)" />
```

(note the `@`).

We actually made this into a helper method, so the final code is

```
<data_set-tag: options="&DataSet.activity_is(activity_for(@this))" />
```

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you tried to post this question to the Hobo Users mailing list -- I got a moderation message, but it doesn't appear that your post got posted, nor can I find it to let it through.   Please try reposting it, there are several helpful people on the list that don't monitor the Hobo tag here.

In Hobo 1.3, the new action doesn't support part AJAX, so there really isn't much magic.  You can just replace the action with your own:

```
def new_for_page
  @activity = Activity.find(...)
  @page = Page.find(params[:page_id])
  @widget = @page.widgets.new
end
```

There is a little bit of magic referenced above:   if you're in WidgetsController, assigning to @widget will also assign to `this`.

But as you said, the knowledge is obviously in there somewhere, and your custom controller action shouldn't be necessary.

This statement seems wrong:  *However, for a new Widget, this fails messily, because either &this or &this.page is not yet set.*

It looks like you're properly using owner actions.  `/pages/:page_id/widgets/new` is the route.   In widgets_controller it's the `new_for_page` action.  In a new or new_for action, `this` is set to an unsaved version of the object.   In your action, it should have been created with the equivalent of `Page.find(params[:page]).widgets.new`.   In other words, both `this` and `this.page` should be populated.

I'm sure you didn't make your statement up out of thin air, so there's probably something else going on.

Comment: I didn't try to post it to the Hobo User's mailing list; I didn't know one existed, although I'm unsurprised. Maybe it got automatically redirected by something? Anyway, this answer gives me a few footholds to explore, thanks! I'll come back in a bit and either report success or refine my question.

Comment: The first thing I learned from this answer: I didn't/don't understand what `this` is. (I mean, I understand the construction, but I don't always understand what Hobo sets it to.)

Comment: :S Well, I have some agreement that `&this.page.activity` *should* work, but doesn't. Our latest strategy was a helper in `app/helpers/application_helper.rb` which takes `&this` as an argument and returns the appropriate `Activity`, but when called with `&this` as an argument it says "Wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)." Grrr...

Comment: pj, if you can pull your problem out into a public project on github, I can take a look for you.

Comment: That I can do; we always work in public. https://github.com/concord-consortium/smartgraphs-authoring/tree/scope-datasets-to-activities - note the branch.

Comment: I seem to be in business using something like `DataSet.activity_is(@this.page.activity)`.